# JSON from API call to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to get an API call and save it as a dataframe.
problem is that I need the data from the 'result' column. 
Didn't succeed to do that.

I'm basically just trying to save the API call as a csv file in order to work with it.

P.S when I do this with a "JSON to CSV converter" from the web it does it as I wish. (example: https://konklone.io/json/)

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

res = requests.get("http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&
address=0xddbd2b932c763ba5b1b7ae3b362eac3e8d40121a&startblock=0&
endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken")

j = res.json()

j

df = pd.DataFrame(j)

df.head()
```

[output example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCInx.png)

Comment: good question, had the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

res = requests.get("http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0xddbd2b932c763ba5b1b7ae3b362eac3e8d40121a&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken")

j = res.json()

# print(j)
filename ="temp.csv"
df = pd.DataFrame(j['result'])

print(df.head())
df.to_csv(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(j["result"])
```